# How to select certain rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a promotion and relegation between two leagues where the top two teams from `LeagueID 2` moves up to `LeagueID 1` and the bottom two teams from `LeagueID 1` moves down to `LeagueID 2`.

My question is how to select those teams, bearing in mind the number of team per league may change in the future, so I cannot for relegating teams use a where clause on position. I can use a where clause for promotion no problem for position 1 and 2 from `LeagueID 2` but if there is a way to do it from a select and a count then I will go for that method as well.

I know all I need to do when we select the correct teams is just update their LeagueIDs.

[image]

LATEST UPDATE:

```
UPDATE dbo.League
SET LeagueId = 2
WHERE LeagueId  = 1
AND Position IN
(
    SELECT TOP 2 Position
    FROM dbo.League_Table
    WHERE LeagueID = 1
    ORDER BY Position DESC
)

UPDATE dbo.League
SET LeagueId = 1
WHERE LeagueId  = 2
AND Position IN
(
    SELECT TOP 2 Position
    FROM dbo.League_Table
    WHERE LeagueID = 2
    ORDER BY Position
)
```

'Team' Table: This table is a reference for all teams and which league they play in:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Team]
(
    [TeamID] TINYINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [TeamAbbreviation] CHAR(3) UNIQUE, 
    [TeamName] VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE, 
    [LeagueID] TINYINT CONSTRAINT FK_Team_League FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES League(LeagueID), 
    [CountryID] TINYINT CONSTRAINT FK_Team_Country FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Country(CountryID)
)
```

'League' Table: Reference to all the leagues:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[League]
(
    [LeagueID] TINYINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [LeagueName] VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE, 
    [MinLeagueWeight] INT,
    [MaxLeagueWeight] INT,
    [CountryID] TINYINT CONSTRAINT FK_League_Country FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Country(CountryID), 
    [ParentLeagueID] TINYINT CONSTRAINT FK_League_ParentLeague FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES League(LeagueID)
)
```

'League_Table' table: This is the league table made up from a view (as seen in the screenshot above):

```
SELECT [Position], [TeamName], [Played], [Wins], [Loss], [Draws], [Points], [Goals_Scored], [Goals_Against], [Goal_Difference], [LeagueID]  
FROM League_Table
```

Comment: Virtually this season there are 12 teams in leagueID 1 and 12 teams in LeagueID 2, but lets say next season i want to expand a league (say 14), then I am looking for a different team position as previous season will be looking for teams 11 and 12 to go down, but next season it's 13 and 14

Comment: How do you define top 2 teams and bottom 2 teams? I mean what are the conditions to be top and bottom?

Comment: @KaiserNayan one would expect the first two positions are top and the last two are bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can order descending for the bottom two, no matter how many there are

```
SELECT TOP 2 * 
FROM Teams 
WHERE LeagueID = 1 
ORDER BY Position DESC
```

(Sidenote: Im hoping your `Position` field is calculated, because if you maintain it that could affect the integrity of your data)

---

Your 2 queries are fine, and combining them into one, although possible, will be less clear. You're simply missing a `WHERE` clause in the subqueries

```
UPDATE dbo.League
SET LeagueId = 2
WHERE LeagueId  = 1
AND Position IN
(
    SELECT TOP 2 Position
    FROM dbo.League 
    WHERE LeagueID = 1
    ORDER BY Position DESC
)

UPDATE dbo.League
SET LeagueId = 1
WHERE LeagueId  = 2
AND Position IN
(
    SELECT TOP 2 Position
    FROM dbo.League 
    WHERE LeagueID = 2
    ORDER BY Position
)
```

---

Another try at this - this time with a single query. H/T to @Jens for providing a test case.

If you first work out how every team's league position changes:

```
SELECT LeagueID, TeamName, case
    when league>1 AND RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY league ORDER BY position ASC) <= 2 THEN -1
    when league<2 AND RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY league ORDER BY position DESC) <= 2 THEN 1
    else 0
end as leaguechange
FROM dbo.League_Table
```

(Note I have put in an extra 2 clauses there - `league>1` to stop a team being promoted to league 0 and `league<2` to stop teams being demoted to league 3 - both of these can be adjusted accordingly)

Once you have that, it can be used as a subquery within a single `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE dbo.Team
SET LeagueID = LeagueID + leaguechange
FROM (
    SELECT LeagueID, TeamName, case
        when league>1 AND RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY leagueID ORDER BY position ASC) <= 2 THEN -1
        when league<2 AND RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY leagueID ORDER BY position DESC) <= 2 THEN 1
        else 0
    end as leaguechange
    FROM dbo.League_Table
) c
INNER JOIN dbo.Team t
 ON c.LeagueId = t.LeagueID
 AND c.TeamName = t.TeamName
```

Comment: I posted an update with your select statement within a update statement. I have two update statements but just wanted to know if this can be combined to one?

Comment: @DazzleVision why do you need it to be one statement? It's fine as two IMO

Comment: That's fine, I didn't know if there was a shorter way of doing it. I do have one little problem with the update though as it seems not to perform it. Each team are assigned a LeagueID and that should be updated but I think the issue is the WHERE clause I have. Can you have a quick check please if that's the case?

Comment: @DazzleVision you're missing a `where` clause in the subqueries. Answer updated

Comment: Yeah this is the problem I had originally. dbo.League_Table has 'Position' but dbo.Team or dbo.League does not have this, so it gives me an unresolved reference. If I include your code but change the UPDATE from dbo.League to dbo.League_Table, then I get an error because I have a group by within. What I need to do is simply UPDATE dbo.Team based on finding their position from the league table

Comment: @DazzleVision I have no idea what that meant. You've just introduced 3 different table names, and your original question had 1. Have you asked us an accurate question?

Comment: My bad, i should have included the whole table schemas, let me display the schemas and what you'll realise is that 'Position' is not referenced because it is only 'League_Table' table and not 'League' table, this makes the 'AND position IN' clause have an unresolved reference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115809/discussion-between-jamiec-and-dazzle-vision).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have this dynamically over different leagues you can also work with RANK():

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(league int, name varchar(10), position int);

INSERT INTO @TABLE
VALUES (1, 'Team A', 1),
       (1, 'Team B', 2),
       (1, 'Team C', 3),
       (1, 'Team D', 4),
       (1, 'Team E', 5),
       (1, 'Team F', 6),
       (1, 'Team G', 7),
       (1, 'Team H', 8),
       (1, 'Team I', 9),
       (1, 'Team J', 10),
       (1, 'Team K', 11),
       (2, 'Team A', 1),
       (2, 'Team B', 2),
       (2, 'Team C', 3),
       (2, 'Team D', 4),
       (2, 'Team E', 5),
       (2, 'Team F', 6),
       (2, 'Team G', 7),
       (2, 'Team H', 8),
       (2, 'Team I', 9),
       (2, 'Team J', 10),
       (2, 'Team K', 11);

SELECT league, name, position
FROM (SELECT *
           , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY league ORDER BY position ASC) AS TopRank
           , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY league ORDER BY position DESC) AS BottomRank
      FROM   @TABLE) RankedResults
WHERE TopRank <= 2
   OR BottomRank <= 2;
```

Result:

```
league      name       position
----------- ---------- -----------
1           Team K     11
1           Team J     10
1           Team B     2
1           Team A     1
2           Team K     11
2           Team J     10
2           Team B     2
2           Team A     1
```

Edit: The TopRanked field is obviously not really required as you could just filter on position, but serves a purpose as kind of an explanation of my approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE League
SET LeagueId = 2,
    Position = NULL
WHERE LeagueId  = 1
AND Position IN
(
    SELECT TOP 2 Position
    FROM League 
    ORDER BY Position DESC
)
```

---

If you want to combine the update-statement for relegation and promotion you could use this:

```
WITH NewLeague AS
(
   SELECT NewLeagueId = CASE WHEN LeagueId  = 1 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, *
   FROM dbo.League
   WHERE 
   (
     LeagueId  = 1
     AND Position IN
     (
       SELECT TOP 2 Position
       FROM dbo.League 
       ORDER BY Position DESC
     )
   )
   OR
   (
     LeagueId  = 2
     AND Position IN
     (
       SELECT TOP 2 Position
       FROM dbo.League 
       ORDER BY Position ASC
     )
   )
)
UPDATE NewLeague 
SET LeagueId = NewLeagueId
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I just have one little question. I provided an update where there are two update statements, one for relegation and the other for promotion. Is there a way these update statements can be combined to one?

Comment: @DazzleVision: provided an approach for one update statement

Comment: Cool Tim, only issue is the execution where it states: Cannot update the view or function 'NewLeague' because it contains aggregates, or a DISTINCT or GROUP BY clause, or PIVOT or UNPIVOT operator.

Comment: I do have a Group By within the view for League_Table so I am assuming that is causing the issue

Comment: @DazzleVision: then you can't write `UPDATE NewLeague ...` but you have to join with the CTE: `UPDATE l SET l.LeagueId = NewLeagueId FROM NewLeague INNER JOIN dbo.League l ON NewLeague.TeamName=l.TeamName`. Btw, you should have a real FK like `TeamId` even if it's unlikely that there are two teams with the same name ;-)